# TinyMCE returning cursor to pre-save location -- API 4

Tags: ajax, tinymce, text-cursor

I'm working on a new install of TinyMCE 4.  The editor is a simple inline DIV, allowing only italic and bold (cleanup is set to remove most other tags).

```
tinymce.init({
    inline: true,

    // we only want simple bold and italic controls
    toolbar: "undo redo | bold italic", 

    invalid_elements : "span,u,a,ul,ol,li,h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6,blockquote,strikethrough",
    ...
```

My problem: I'd like to save the content of my editor back to my database via ajax every few keystrokes.

In order to run the cleanup, I first save the contents:

```
tinyMCE.triggerSave();
```

then get the cleaned-up contents to send back to my database -- which, of course, traps appropriately for code-bombs, etc :)

```
var strData = tinymce.activeEditor.getContent() ;
```

This all works fine except that, back in the editor, the cursor get returned to the *beginning* of the content.

I thought I could return to the correct place by setting a bookmark before saving:

```
// set bookmark
var bm = tinymce.activeEditor.selection.getBookmark();

// save and cleanup, then ajax
tinyMCE.triggerSave(); 
...ajax stuff here

// Restore the selection bookmark
tinymce.activeEditor.selection.moveToBookmark(bm);
```

but this doesn't seem to work.

I also thought I could, perhaps, capture the current node and offset before saving:

```
var nd = tinymce.activeEditor.selection.getNode();
var os = tinymce.activeEditor.selection.getRng().startOffset;
```

and return to the correct point by:

```
tinymce.activeEditor.setCursorLocation(nd, os);
```

but this creates an error, as nd is apparently not a valid node object.

Is this because my 'selection' is actually a zero-length string (it's a cursor point, rather than a selection)?

I'm afraid that I'm having a few difficulties with the official documentation for API 4, which isn't as 'fleshed out' as the documentation for API 3 (I guess because it's a recent update).

Most of the help and examples that I can find on Stackoverflow (and general googling) relate to API 3 (which it seems is quite a different beast).

Can anyone advise me if what I want is possible?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Hmm, you could use a non-html bookmark:

```
// set bookmark
var bm = tinymce.activeEditor.selection.getBookmark(2,true);

// save and cleanup, then ajax
tinyMCE.triggerSave(); 
...ajax stuff here

// Restore the selection bookmark
tinymce.activeEditor.selection.moveToBookmark(bm);
```

Comment: You hero! That worked perfectly!  But this highlights my difficulty with the API documentation, which explains the getBookmark 'type' argument as: `Number  Optional state if the bookmark should be simple or not. Default is complex.`  No listing of which numbers correspond to which options, nor what the different options can be used for.  Difficult for a newbie like me!

Comment: i totally agree, the parameters for the getBookmark function never have been documented well. an additional sidemark here: tinymce.activeEditor might work for now, but in case you are using more than one editor on a page you should use tinymce.get('your_editor_id') instead

Comment: Thanks for that advice.  My site uses only small inline editors -- TinyMCE closes them on blur, so I assumed that they become inactive... so could only ever have one active editor.  I'd better check!